# jQuery selector debugger

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, jquery-selectors

I recently started to work on existing project. The previous developer had a lot of javascript and html template files. Over time, he removed pieces of code from this files leaving parts without any reference (see the examples).

For example

- (a) a button without a click event
- (b) a jquery selector without a DOM element inside the HTML: `$('#someSelector')` but `<someElement id="someSelector"></someElement>` doesn't exists.

The case (a) is quite simple to solve, because I just see the unused element and I delete it from the appropriate file.

The second part is a little bit more difficult, because the browser console is not firing an error when jQuery does not find a selector.

I can test selectors using something like this:

```
if($('theSelector').length ){
    //alert or console, the selector matches some element.
}
```

This technique is very expensive in time, because I need to test one by one every selector.

Is there a tool for automate this task? I tried FireQuery (a firefox plugin) but it is not giving me good results.

P.S:
The project is not using a javascript framework nor system template. (really bad!)

Comment: It's totally normal for some selectors to select 0 elements on some pages. That's not an error state most of the time.

Comment: Have you considered that some content may be dynamically generated as a result of user interaction therefore putting into the DOM elements that did not exist at page load?

Comment: if it is for the dev environment, then [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u4fes688/1/) it overrides the default jQuery with a custom version and logs a warning message when a jQuery invokaction does not return an element... then you can investigate only the logged statement calles

Comment: @meagar Yes, I agree. But I need to detect all of these cases. If any selector return 0 elements, in this case the element was deleted or on the current page the element doesn't exists.

Comment: @user3558931 Yes. I will cover these cases. The problem is not with the elements generated dynamically, just I need to check if the selector is matching some element, if not I will check if this element was deleted from html files (or check if it will generated dinamically)

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes! is only for dev env. I need to remove unused code ;). I will take a look to your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can kick the tires for a bit after modifying $ to log it's calls.
load the following script

```
var $$=$, log=[];
$=function(s){
  log.push(s);
  return $$.apply(this, arguments);
};
$$.extend($,$$);
```

now click around and do "everything" jQuery does on the site, then run:

```
console.log(log.filter(function(s){
  return jQuery(s).length===0;
}));
```

to dump a list of un-realized selectors to the console. of course, fix the problems and remove this code because it slows jQuery down a lot, and it might not be 100% compatible with all plugins, but it works on the quick tests i did here on stack via the console. you might also consider shadowing "jQuery" in addition to "$" to capture noconflict usages.

Comment: i didn't see the fiddle in the comment, but its somewhat like mine. the extend() call in mine does prevent a lot of errors though, so i'll leave it up...