# How can I tell what I am iterating over in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I am debugging jQuery code, how can I tell what elements my selector is operating on?

I just spent a couple of hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong with this code that is supposed to turn off one input field and turn on another:

```
<input id="qty-dropdown" ...>
<input id="qty-box" ...>
...
$('.qty-dropdown').hide();
$('.qty-box').show();
```

and of course the problem was that it should have been

```
$('#qty-dropdown').hide();   // # for ID, not . for class
$('#qty-box').show();
```

I was working on figuring if I was calling `hide()` and `show()` incorrectly, and not realizing I was operating on zero elements.  If I had been able to tell that `$('.qty-dropdown')` was selecting no elements, I'd have saved a lot of time.

Is there anything I can do like:

```
$('.some-selector').dump()?
```

that will give me debugging information?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375877/jquery-selector-debugger) has an answer with a chunk of code that looks like it should dump into the console, but dropping that into my code didn't seem to put anything into my Firebug console.

I also realize that my original problem could have been solved with:

```
alert( $('#js-qty-dropdown').length );
```

but I am looking for a more complete solution for next time.

Comment: `console.log($(yourSelector))` to see if you're even operating on a jQuery object.

Comment: *"but I am looking for a more complete solution for next time."* What would you consider a "more complete" solution? You could always create a $.fn.dump function that logs the items in the collection, though... don't see why you would do that over `console.log($(selector).get())`

Comment: I didn't realize I could call `console.log` with objects.  That changes everything.

Comment: You can also get the original selector used to fill the jQuery object using the `selector` property. For example: `$('div.header').selector;`.

Comment: If you have an issue that you just cant figure out, you could always set a debugger before the code runs and look at the results in a Watch window or from the console. None of these things will tell you that your selector was wrong or why, though. Just that your selector didn't return any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery objects act kind of like arrays. Get the number of elements selected:

```
$('.qty-dropdown').length
```

If you are using Chrome for debugging, you can log out the object and hover over the different elements, and it will highlight them on the page:

```
console.log($('.qty-dropdown'));
```